# Remove enter parameter value MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

How to remove enter parameter value in `MS Access 2007`

Here is my Code

```
SELECT tblPersonalInfo.studentId,
       tblPersonalInfo.lastName AS tblPersonalInfo_lastName,
       tblPersonalInfo.firstName AS tblPersonalInfo_firstName,
       tblmom.firstName AS tblmom_firstName,
       tblmom.lastName AS tblmom_lastName
FROM tblmom
INNER JOIN (tblDad
            INNER JOIN (tblContactPerson
                        INNER JOIN tblPersonalInfo ON tblContactPerson.contactId=tblPersonalInfo.contactId) ON tblDad.dadId=tblPersonalInfo.dadId) ON tblmom.momId=tblPersonalInfo.momId
WHERE (((tblPersonalInfo.studentId)=[Forms]![formPi]![dadId]));
```

Comment: You might want to explain your question a bit into more detail, what is an 'enter parameter' and what are you trying to achieve? Also what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Diether, your query is looking for a value in the control on a form to get a value for tblPeraonlInfo.studentID to filter by.  The expression:

```
[Forms]![formPi]![dadId]
```

is the reference to the form.  If the form isn't open or Access can't otherwise get to the control on the form, Access will default to the behavior of popping up an input box and asking the user to enter the parameter.  If you remove [Forms]![formPi]![dadId] from your query (you actually would need to pull out the whole WHERE clause line, or hardcode a value for studentID), it will stop asking you to enter a value.  However, realize there will be no more reference to the form in the query and it will likely stop working the way you expect it to in its context in your app, so be wary.